# Creating a list variable using a generic for the add method in the SinglyLinkedList class

Tags: java, generics, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a list variable containing ((1 2) () (3 4 5) (6)) using my SinglyLinkedList class.

This is the add method I have implemented:

```
  public void add(T...x) {  
    for(T i:x) {
    n++;
    if (head == null) 
      head = new Node((T) i);
    else {
      Node p = head;
      while (p.next != null)
        p = p.next;
      p.next = new Node((T) i);
    }
    }
  }
```

Do I need to add anything to make it take a list of list of numbers?
I get an error when I try to do list.add((1 2)) or list.add(()). However it works fine when I add non-collection items like list.add(1). Thanks in advance.

Comment: `list.add((1 2))` is not Java compilable code. Please post exactly the lines you executed and the error you get. You'd better read first [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I agree. However, in my HW assignment thats how its read so I'm assuming its a typo and meant for commas to be inserted.